Fine-tuned Phi-2 model did not work correctly, when save it as pytorch or Pickle
I have a problem here I did fine tune Phi-2 model with LoRA, and I saved the model as a safe-tensors , and here is what is inside my folder
phi-2-sxd\adapter_config.json
phi-2-sxd\adapter_model.safetensors
phi-2-sxd\README.md

the safe-tensors model is working very well: here is how I make predictions
from transformers import pipeline, PhiForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

# Load the fine-tuned model and tokenizer
model = PhiForCausalLM.from_pretrained("phi-2-sxd/")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/phi-2", trust_remote_code=True)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.padding_side = "right"

# Create the text generation pipeline
pipe = pipeline(task="text-generation", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, max_length=300)

# Generate text based on the provided prompt
prompt = "I have been experiencing joint pain in my fingers, wrists, and knees. The pain is often achy and throbbing, and it gets worse when I move my joints"
result = pipe(f"[answer]: {prompt}")
print(result[0]['generated_text'])

but I want to convert that to pth (Pytorch) or Pickle (pkl) but in the end the output file was so big like 12GB.
and that was not the only problem, I tried many times, to save it in pth ,pkl and h5, but in the end I got these long error
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for PhiForCausalLM: Missing key(s) in state_dict: HERE_IS_LIST_OF_MISSING_LAYERS

here are my many attempts to save it:

# Save it in Pytorch
from transformers import PhiForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch

model = PhiForCausalLM.from_pretrained("phi-2-sxd/")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/phi-2", trust_remote_code=True)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.padding_side = "right"

# Save the model's tensors to a PyTorch file
torch.save(model.state_dict(), "Phi-2-SXD.pth")


# save the model using H5 format
from transformers import PhiForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
import h5py

model = PhiForCausalLM.from_pretrained("phi-2-sxd/")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/phi-2", trust_remote_code=True)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.padding_side = "right"

# Save the model to H5 format
with h5py.File("Phi-2-SXD.h5", "w") as f:
    for name, param in model.state_dict().items():
        f.create_dataset(name, data=param.detach().numpy())

# save the model using H5 format with compression
import h5py
from transformers import PhiForCausalLM,AutoTokenizer

model = PhiForCausalLM.from_pretrained("phi-2-sxd/")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/phi-2", trust_remote_code=True)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.padding_side = "right"

# Save the model to H5 format with compression
with h5py.File("Phi-2-SXD.h5", "w", libver="latest") as f:
    for name, param in model.state_dict().items():
        f.create_dataset(name, data=param.detach().numpy(), compression="gzip", compression_opts=9) 


# Save it in Pytorch with some tricks to reduce the size
import torch
from transformers import PhiForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
from transformers.modeling_utils import LoRAModel
from torch.nn.utils import prune

model = PhiForCausalLM.from_pretrained("phi-2-sxd/")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/phi-2", trust_remote_code=True)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.padding_side = "right"

# Prune the model
for name, module in model.named_modules():
    if isinstance(module, torch.nn.Linear):
        prune.l1_unstructured(module, name="weight", amount=0.5)
    elif isinstance(module, LoRAModel):
        prune.l1_unstructured(module.lora_A, name="weight", amount=0.5)
        prune.l1_unstructured(module.lora_B, name="weight", amount=0.5)

# Save the pruned model
torch.save(model.state_dict(), "Phi-2-SXD-pruned.pth")




# pytorch with quantize

import torch
from transformers import PhiForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
from torch.quantization import quantize, quantize_dynamic

model = PhiForCausalLM.from_pretrained("phi-2-sxd/")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/phi-2", trust_remote_code=True)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.padding_side = "right"
# Dynamically quantize the model
quantized_model = quantize_dynamic(model, {torch.nn.Linear}, dtype=torch.qint8)

# Save the quantized model
torch.save(quantized_model.state_dict(), "Phi-2-SXD-quantized.pth")

# Both Technik
import torch
from transformers import PhiForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
from torch.nn.utils import prune
from torch.quantization import quantize, quantize_dynamic

model = PhiForCausalLM.from_pretrained("phi-2-sxd/")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/phi-2", trust_remote_code=True)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.padding_side = "right"

# Dynamically quantize the model
quantized_model = quantize_dynamic(model, {torch.nn.Linear}, dtype=torch.qint8)

# Prune the quantized model
for name, module in quantized_model.named_modules():
    if isinstance(module, torch.nn.Linear):
        prune.l1_unstructured(module, name="weight", amount=0.5)

# Save the pruned and quantized model
torch.save(quantized_model.state_dict(), "Phi-2-SXD-quantized-pruned.pth")

What should I do to get my Pth, or pkl working just like safe-tensors?
I have even try to disable the strict mode:
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("Phi-2-SXD.pth", map_location=device), strict=False) 

and even Check if the model is wrapped in DataParallel
if isinstance(quantized_model, torch.nn.DataParallel):
    quantized_model = quantized_model.module

It works, but the model prediction is making no sense at all, just garbage.
Thanks a lot in advance.
I am trying to save my safe-tensors as Pth or pkl files, to be load faster, and easier.
